# This question should not be put in review queue

Tags: discussion, review-queues, answers, disputed-review-audits

I think this question should be removed as a guard from the review queue:

https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/15708186

When I review this question as *No Action Needed*, the warning shows:

**STOP! Look and Listen.**...

The reason this is a bad answer is that, there is already an older answer, which is *much shorter and therefor easier to maintain and read*.

But how could the reviewers know, since our review page only shows the answer need to be reviewed.

What do you think?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You're right: this was a bad audit. I thought it was a decent one, but, as you pointed out, you can't see comments on a late-answer review audit. I thought you could, but I've confirmed (with Shog9) that you cannot.

So, it's a lousy audit. It's inevitable that we'll have some bad ones with a system this complex. I've lifted your review ban, so you can just ignore this and move on.

Pro tip: when you see a post that looks "suspicious" - as in, it's not clear why it's in the review queue - clicking through to look at the context can be very helpful. :)

Happy reviewing!

Comment: FP and LA are, fortunately, the only queues that deliberately hide comments on audits. Why they do this at all I have never been able to determine.

Comment: @NathanTuggy: Presumably, it's to make the posts look as if they were new, with no comments on them yet. What I'm not convinced of is that this is actually a good idea. Perhaps a reasonable compromise would be to hide the comments only for *high quality* audit posts (which often have lots of positive comments that could easily spoil the audit if shown), but show them for *low quality* audits (which, if they've received any comments at all before being deleted, IME typically just have one or two comments explaining what's wrong with them).

Comment: What @IlmariKaronen said. Personally, I'd prefer to just show the comments in all cases. The main point of the audit is to see if you're paying attention instead of robo-reviewing. If you're looking at the comments for context, you're paying attention.

Comment: The real question is why that answer was deleted in the first place. It was posted 8 minutes after the accepted one, probably they were typing out the answer at the same time. Perhaps not the best answer, but a valid answer still. Was it deleted by the person who posted it?